# Visual Studio Code Format Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, format

I would like to know if there is an extension to automatically format and indent code on visual studio code

Comment: have you read the doc, and searched the marketplace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Prettier` code formatter and set it to `format on save` option available on VS Code.

So, whenever you will save your program. Your code will be formatted and indented.

[Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) link here